# Converting an input with shape (m, n) to (m, k, n), where k is "hidden" inside as a string representation of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset like the one in the picture below, with `m` rows (= batch size) and `n` columns (`v1, v2, ... vn`), each representing a feature. For each example in the dataset, each feature is a string representation of an array of floats, so something like this `'[-0.05, 1.12, -0.23, ..., 1.22]'`. The "hidden" array represented as a string, if converted to an array of floats, has length `k`. This input is fed directly into a Tensorflow/Keras model **without** any Python preprocessing: the dataset is passed *as is* to  `model.fit`, so there is no way to do conversions and reshaping in Pandas or Numpy.

Is there a way to convert and reshape inside the model, as the first layer? The model takes the input with shape `(m, n)`, extract the hidden array of length `k` and rearrange the input shape to `(m, k, n)`

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, You can't feed **strings** into the model directly. You will need to convert it to **float** first.

You can't reshape the data from inside the model but what you can do is to set the input shape to **None**. If your input data shape is not fixed, you can set input shape to **None**. In this case, your model will accept data of any shape.

You can take a look into the discussion here too.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2054